# Automator workflow crashing silently when ran as Finder extension

Tags: finder, automator, script, automation

I made an Automator workflow that essentially runs a shell script to optimize images. I intend to use it as a Finder.app extension, by selecting images and running the workflow as a "quick action".

With a small number of high resolution images (tested with about 10), the workflow runs perfectly well in both Automator.app and in Finder.app:

[image: Screenshot from Automator.app. Images from Finder.app are handed over to a shell script that loops over them and calls a Node.js script for each of their file paths. The Node.js script optimizes the images and saves them to a destination folder. Finally, the workflow opens the destination folder in Finder.app. We see in the Automator.app log that the workflow runs successfully.]

*Note: when using via Finder.app, I remove the "Get Specified Finder Items" step. This is only for testing in Automator.app.*

Here's the shell script with comments. The bulk of the image processing happens in a Node.js script (I'm not including this one here because I'm confident it's not the issue, see below).

```sh
for f in "$@"
do
    # pass each file name as a CLI arg to a Node.js script
    $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v19.3.0/bin/node $HOME/Developer/image-processing/index.js $f
    # (not relevant here:) notify when an image is processed
    osascript -e "display notification \"Optimized file: $f \" with title \"Automation\""
done

# (not relevant here:) echo the output folder of images, so that it can be opened by the "Reveal Finder Items" action
echo $HOME/Desktop/PROCESSED_IMAGES
```

The issue is with a high number of inputs. I tried with about ~1000 high-resolution images, and while it still works (slowly) via Automator.app, nothing happens when I try to run the workflow via Finder.app. No image at all is being processed (when using Automator.app, I see them being saved to the destination folder one after the other), and it doesn't seem that the Node.js script is crashing/erroring (it logs errors).

I have a feeling that this is a memory issue. Are there known limitations to Finder.app extensions? Is there a way to debug this further?

#### EDIT: taking Node.js and image processing out of the equation

I understand that it can be tricky to debug a workflow that includes things like a Node.js image processing script, even though I was pretty confident this wasn't the issue (see above).

So I removed the image processing part: I can reproduce the issue with the simple shell script below.

```
touch $HOME/Desktop/log.txt
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f" >> $HOME/Desktop/log.txt
done
```

This loops over files and appends their paths to log.txt. It works as expected with few images, or when running it inside Automator.app, but fails silently when I try to run it on ~1000 image files from Finder.app. Same as my original post then, but without Node.js. This should hopefully be reproducible on other machines (I'm on an M1 Pro with macOS Ventura).

#### Edit 2: I'm pretty sure this is a macOS limitation

So the minimal reproduction above helped me debug faster. The script works as expected with up to exactly 1000 files. At 1001, it fails silently. This makes me pretty confident that this is a limitation to Finder.app extensions.

Any documentation on this would be welcome though (couldn't find anything), plus any workaround ideas for workflow like this one.

Comment: Can you pls add to your post a screenshot of the Automator quick action as well as a text copy of the AppleScript code used in the quick action?

Comment: Thanks @Alper, done :) I'm not sure it's going to be much help though—the workflow and shell script are very straightforward. It seems that the script is not being triggered at all when using many images

Comment: I also added a snippet using only shell (no Node.js) where I can reproduce the same issue

Comment: So this is probably an artificial Finder.app limitation, see edit #2 in my post. I'd love to find proper docs for this as well as a workaround, so I'll keep this question open for now